# How to add add if condition in AWS SES html template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

Requirement is to send templated mail based on received bodydata from api. BodyData may not contain some tags. see below sample Template part.

```
<p>{{sender}} has invited you to join team {{teamName}}</p>
```

so body data may not contain teamName. So I want to put if condition on {{teamName}} in template.

Please help me here to find solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For conditional logic in an SES template you can use if else statements like you would in code. For your example you would use something like

```
<p>{{sender}} has invited you to join team {{#if teamName}}{{teamName}}{{/if}}</p>
```

Taken from the following documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-personalized-email-advanced.html