# How to add advanced if condition in AWS SES HTML template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is there a way to create a conditional test that an object meets specific criteria more than exists/doesn't exist in an AWS SES HTML template?  For example, `{{#if x > 5}}{{x}}{{/if}}` instead of `{{#if x}}{{x}}{{/if}}`?

I've read the docs here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-personalized-email-advanced.html) and seen a good SO question/answer here ([How to add add if condition in AWS SES html template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474310/how-to-add-add-if-condition-in-aws-ses-html-template)), but neither one talked about an `if` statement that was more than a check on if an object exists.

Comment: Have you found a way to implement Helpers?